# Page cant access set context

Tags: html-framework-7

I am returning context data to a route but for some reason i cannot access the context data in the template like so.

Route:

```
{
  path: "/select-vans/",
  component: SelectVans,
  context: {
    vans: [
      {
        VAN_ID: 1,
        NAME: "Van 01"
      },
      {
        VAN_ID: 2,
        NAME: "Van 02"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Template (HTML Part):

```
<div>
  <ul>
    {{#each vans}}
    <li>{{ VAN_ID }} {{ NAME }}</li>
    {{else}}
    <li>No properties</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

But no matter what i do it always returns `No properties`, i have tried passing it as data and changing `vans` to `this.vans` but to no avail. If i log the page in the console on `init` i can see the context in `page.route.route.context` to the context does exist but the template can't seem to access it.

Edit: I got it to work by changing `vans` to `$route.route.context.vans`, surely there is a less convoluted way to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign it to variable and use it instead of `$route.route.context.vans` like this:

```
let vans = $route.route.context.vans
```

In my project I use this method and it works fine :)